# How can I use Julia for the first time on windows 7?

Tags: windows, julia

When I try to install any package in Julia, I keep receiving this error:

```
julia> Pkg.add("Dates")
INFO: Initializing package repository C:\Users\Ezz\.julia\v0.6
INFO: Cloning METADATA from https://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl
ERROR: GitError(Code:ECERTIFICATE, Class:OS, user cancelled certificate check: )

Stacktrace:
 [1] macro expansion at .\libgit2\error.jl:99 [inlined]
 [2] clone(::String, ::String, ::Base.LibGit2.CloneOptions) at .\libgit2\reposit
ory.jl:276
 [3] #clone#100(::String, ::Bool, ::Ptr{Void}, ::Nullable{Base.LibGit2.AbstractC
redentials}, ::Function, ::String, ::String) at .\libgit2\libgit2.jl:562
 [4] (::Base.LibGit2.#kw##clone)(::Array{Any,1}, ::Base.LibGit2.#clone, ::String
, ::String) at .\<missing>:0
 [5] (::Base.Pkg.Dir.##8#10{String,String})() at .\pkg\dir.jl:55
 [6] cd(::Base.Pkg.Dir.##8#10{String,String}, ::String) at .\file.jl:59
 [7] init(::String, ::String) at .\pkg\dir.jl:53
 [8] #cd#1(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Function, ::String, ::Vararg{String,N}
where N) at .\pkg\dir.jl:28
 [9] add(::String) at .\pkg\pkg.jl:117
```

I googled and found that TLS protocol is not installed and this can be done by installing the easy fix, but it didn't work. I might understood something wrong, so please can anybody help me?

I'm using windows 7, 64-bit.

Comment: You shouldn't be installing anything for SSL connection with a legitimate website to work. You might be behind some proxy that does nasty things with HTTPS certificates. Anyway, it's not related to Julia at all.

Comment: @scrutari Thanks, so what should I do?

Comment: Does the link `https://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl` work for you in a web browser? Have you obtained Julia from https://julialang.org/downloads/?

Comment: @scrutari Yes, the github link works but why? Yes I have downloaded Julia from its website.

Comment: Try cloning that Git repo manually from GitHub just to check that git works for you. Your error might be caused by your Git configuration.

Comment: Does `Pkg.init()` work for you?

Comment: Cloning is done correctly. `Pkg.init()` produces the same error.

Comment: Have you installed the two update on the julia download page? namely [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-a-default-secure-protocols-in) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/readme)